# How to make buttons on popup module work?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the click-me button that leads to a popup module (popup-container). However, the click me button and the "x" close button do not work/function. I believe I am calling the class/id correctly. Are the buttons not working properly? Can anyone provide clarity? Thank you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="myscripts.js"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<button id="btn">Click me!</button>

<body>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Figtree:wght@500&family=Inter:wght@100;300;400;500&family=Montserrat&family=Plus+Jakarta+Sans:wght@400;500&family=Raleway&family=Roboto&family=Rubik&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <div class="popup-container">
    <header>
      <button id="mybtn" class="close-button" aria-label="Close" type="button">
<span aria-hidden = "true">&times;</span>
</button>
      <h1 class="share-button">How to Play</h1>
    </header>
    <div class="space">example</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

```
* {
    font-family: 'Figtree', sans-serif;
    font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  }
  
  body {
    background-color: #fefbd8;
  }
  
  .popup-container {
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 120px auto;
    background-color: #FFFF;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    padding: 2px 30px 30px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    max-width: 500px;
  }
  
  h1 {
    font-size: 23px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #D3D3D3;
  }
  
  .close-button {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: right;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-left: 500px;
    font-size: 30px;
    border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    background-color: #ffff;
  }
  
  .space,
  .space1,
  .space2 {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  
  .space3 {
    padding-top: 10px;
  }
  
  #mybtn:hover,
  #mybtn:focus {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #A5A5A5;
  }
```

```
var modal = document.getElementById("popup-container");

var btn = document.getElementById("btn");

var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("close-button")[0];

btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

button.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Hello. I have the click-me button that leads to a popup module (popup-container). However, the click me button and the "x" close button do not work/function. I believe I am calling the class/id correctly. Are the buttons not working properly? Can anyone provide clarity? Thank you!

Comment: Why not just use a `<dialog>` element instead of complicating your life with an outdated technique?   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog

Comment: `button.onclick` is not defined and gives an error. `btn` is defined two times.

Answer (score 0):

There was a lot of problems in you code but I have fixed it. You can check it out.

```js
var modal = document.querySelector(".popup-container"); // Here you are selecting the modal using Id but you have not given any id to modal

var openBtn = document.getElementById("open-button"); // Your btn id was mismatched hereB

// Use Different variable name for buttons
var closeBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("close-button")[0];

openBtn.onclick = function () {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

closeBtn.onclick = function () {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function (event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
* {
    font-family: 'Figtree', sans-serif;
    font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

body {
    background-color: #fefbd8;
}

.popup-container {
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 120px auto;
    background-color: #FFFF;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    padding: 2px 30px 30px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    max-width: 500px;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 23px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #D3D3D3;
}

.close-button {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: right;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-left: 500px;
    font-size: 30px;
    border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    background-color: #ffff;
}

.space,
.space1,
.space2 {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.space3 {
    padding-top: 10px;
}

#mybtn:hover,
#mybtn:focus {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #A5A5A5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Figtree:wght@500&family=Inter:wght@100;300;400;500&family=Montserrat&family=Plus+Jakarta+Sans:wght@400;500&family=Raleway&family=Roboto&family=Rubik&display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <button id="open-button">Click me!</button>
    <div class="popup-container">
        <header>
            <button id="mybtn" class="close-button" aria-label="Close" type="button">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
            <h1 class="share-button">How to Play</h1>
        </header>
        <div class="space">example</div>
    </div>
    <script src="myscripts.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```